# Ident authentication failed for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, postgresql, centos

I am trying to set up my rails app with a Postgres database which I am new to.

I am using

- centos 6
- postgresql 9.6.2
- pg_hba.conf path => `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

I had logged in with `sudo -u postgres psql` and created a user 'X' with password 'password'. Below are the details

```
postgres=# \l

                                 List of databases

 Name     |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |       Access privileges       
--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------

 postgres     | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 

 template0    | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                  +

      |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres

 template1    | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                  +

      |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres

 trip_staging | X | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/X             +

      |              |          |             |             | X=CTc/X

(4 rows)

postgres=# \du
```

---

```
                             List of roles

  Role name   |                         Attributes                         | Member of 

--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------

 X |                                                            | {}

 postgres     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

When I run command:
`RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:create`

I get the below error:

```
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "X"

Couldn't create database for {"database"=>"trip_staging", "adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"X", "password"=>"password", "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>5432, "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
```

After this I looked up each possible fix for this. I tried changing the pg_hba.conf with below configuration:

```
TYPE  DATABASE USER ADDRESS  METHOD
local  all      all           md5
host   all      all  0.0.0.0  md5 
host   all      all  ::1/128  md5
```

Also tried, changing METHOD with `trust` and then restarted the postgresql server with the command: `sudo service postgresql-9.6 restart` but same error.

Also tried, changing read permissions for path `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` from `600` to `755`. To do that I had to login as postgres superuser with `sudo su - postgres` which is weird. Then restarted the postgresql server

Also tried, changing Method from `ident` to `trust` for path `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf`, as apparently there exists a version wise pg_hba.conf too. Then I restarted the PostgreSQL server.

Nothing seemed to have worked so far. Please help find out what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In the pg_hba.conf the part of 0.0.0.0 needs the mask like this 0.0.0.0/32, in the log says the problem, wich is by default in centos in /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_log/

Comment: Tried that too. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: And when you restart the database didn‘t say some error in the log?